# My useEffect() hook is running multiple times when dispatching a redux event?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-hooks

I currently have a component which builds its payload from the `context` stored in a redux store.

When completing the API call it then dispatches `nextTask` which updates the state of the context causing the effect to run again and be stuck in an infinite loop.

I need to be able to access the `context` when building the payload but only re-fire the fetch event when the url changes. I tried `useCallback` but may have misunderstood.

Here is the component:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Axios from "../../config/AxiosConfig";
import { nextTask } from "../../redux/actions/flowActions";
import { RootState } from "../../redux/reducers/rootReducer";
import { JsonRPC } from "../../types/tasks";

const JsonRpc: React.FC<JsonRPC> = ({
  url,
  method,
  payload,
  payload_paths,
  ...rest
}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const context = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.context.present);

  const getPayload = useCallback(() => {
    console.log(context);
  }, [context]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetch = async () => {
      const payload = getPayload();

      const { data } = await Axios({
        method,
        url,
        // ...opts,
      });

      if (data.result) {
        dispatch(nextTask());
      }
    };

    try {
      fetch();
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }, [url, dispatch, method, getPayload]);
  return null;
};

export default JsonRpc;
```

Comment: is `context` an object or array? if yes then it could be its reference that changes everytime, though its values are the same. there is also `method` dependency, if it's a method no memoized, than it would cause the infinite loop as well.

Comment: @buzatto it is an object yes, the method changes at the same time the url changes its only when adding the `getPayload` dependency that it inifinite loops

Comment: you need probably to memoize your selector, you can use with reselect lib https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors

Comment: @buzatto im not sure that is correct as i do not need to make any calculations based on a selection i just need access to the latest object

Comment: i think you could try shallowEqual

`import { shallowEqual, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

// later
const selectedData = useSelector(selectorReturningObject, shallowEqual)`

Comment: Try removing one of the dependency form the `useEffect` dependency array. It looks like `dispatch` and `getPayload` are not causing the effect to run multiple times and it is `url` or `method` causing the effect to run multiple times